# How to download pdf only viewable in pdf.js?

Tags: macos, firefox, pdf, wget

I use Firefox Version 90 on macOS 11.5 and would like to download a pdf I can view via pdf.js. The link is https://www.laprensa.com.ni/wp-content/plugins/mix-eviewer/pdfjs/web/viewer.php?file=https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s3.laprensa.com.ni-bq/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/LP20210622.pdf&dButton=false&pButton=false&oButton=false&v=1.2#zoom=auto (via https://www.laprensa.com.ni/epaper/2021/06/22).

How can I download the pdf (cache viewer do not exists anymore)? The direct link is https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s3.laprensa.com.ni-bq/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/LP20210622.pdf as shown in Firefox Network Analyser. I tried wget to no avail.

Comment: Maybe the Network Analyser shows any request _headers_ that the server would pay attention to? Try the right-click "Copy as cURL" option?

Comment: I have to say that I am a noob in any of this. The right click to obtain the curl URL functions but do not know what to do with it.

Comment: Look in the `%TEMP%` folder

Comment: If you can view it in pdf.js, you should be able to go to file -> save page as ... and save it locally, just as any page you can display in firefox. But I'm on Windows, maybe there are differences in macOS

Comment: @1NN, can you try it yourself with your system? I cannot download the pdf with your solution. Just wondering if you can with yours. @ desbest, where do I find this folder on macOS?

Comment: I just figured out that the get request is made with `Access-Control-Request-Method` and `Access-Control-Request-Headers`. It this the reason why I cannot access the file via `wget`?

Comment: I got it to work. Just needed to use the curl from Firefox and add -o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings. Search for "pdf". Scroll down in the applications window, and change the setting for "Portable Document Format (pdf)" to "Save file" (see image). Open your link, firefox will save your file. Afterwards, you can change your settings back.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, 1NN! :)